# Showing $\sum_{j=1}^n p_j\log_2\frac1{r_j}-\sum_{j=1}^n p_j\log_2\frac1{p_j}=-\sum_{j=1}^np_j\log_2\frac{r_j}{p_j}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot \log_2\frac1{r_j} - \sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot \log_2\frac1{p_j}
$$
the same as
$$
-\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j \cdot \log_2 \frac{r_j}{p_j}
$$
?

(It is for proving that the kullbach-lieber divergence is nonnegative and first I have to rewrite it)

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}p_j\log_2(1/r_j)-\sum_{j=0}^{n}p_j\log_2(1/p_j)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}p_j(\log_2(1/r_j)-\log_2(1/p_j))$$
Two basic properties of logarithms is that
$$\log_n(a)-\log_n(b)=\log_n(a/b)$$
And
$$\log(a/b)=-\log(b/a)$$
Substituting these into the last sum gives the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at a single value of $j$ and using properties of logarithms:

$p\log\frac1r-p\log\frac1p=p\log\frac{p}{r}=-p\log\frac{r}{p}$